# What is the difference between Eldians and The Subjects of Ymir?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In season 3 of *Attack on Titan*, what’s the difference between Eldians and The Subjects of Ymir?

Answer (score 3):

Eldians refer to people living in [Eldia](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Eldia), a former nation. They comprise of:

- The Subjects of Ymir
- The Ackerman Clan
- The Azumabito Clan

The [Subjects of Ymir](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Subjects_of_Ymir) are people directly descended from Ymir Fritz. They are also Eldians as they were living in Eldia together with the Ackerman and Azumabito clans. As stated in the wiki, they are the

> only race capable of becoming Titans.

All Subjects of Ymir were Eldians but not all Eldians were Subjects of Ymir.